# ESQL code for CSV to XML conversion in IIB v10

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I want to convert input CSV file to XML file using ESQL in IIB v10. Can you please help me with the ESQL code to achieve the same. I've provided the Input CSV file sample and Output XML file sample as below:

[Input CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBIfy.jpg)

[Output XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyn91.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is fundamentally wrong. Using ESQL only to do it on Integration Bus is like using a knife to cut down a tree (when you have the choice with a chainsaw). If you want to convert a csv file to an xml, the proper solution is the following :

1) Define a new DFDL schema to parse the CSV file

2) Define your xsd for the output XML

3) Use the DFDL parser when you read the CSV, and use the structure you created (on the fileInput node for example, I don't know your exact case)

4) Use a mapping node to map from your DFDL structure to your XML structure (defined in the xsd)

Note : the last step can be done with alternatives solution, like compute Nodes (ESQL, Java, C#, php).

If you have any additional questions, feel free to contact me

Comment: i don't agree with you, the question is not fundamentally wrong because maybe the input file is so big(more than 1gb) that it will be better to do with ESQL and not with Mapping.

Comment: Hello Gabriel. I agree with you on the file size, but I have two thing to add to your comment. 
First, IIB is not designed to handle 1Go files. As defined by IBM, messages between 5 Mo and 10 Mo are considered as large, messages over 10 Mo are not recommended and requires special treatment.
Second, choosing to use csv to transfer 1Go of data is definitely a weird choice, and probably the worst one (but I know, sometime we have to work with that kind of bad choice)
My comment was based on the question itself, someone asking such a question is probably not handling specific case you described

Comment: Can you provide some references? Some links from IBM that say that? Because i never read anything from IBM that said that. I have used IIB for processing large file(500MB), using as reference this article [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.scenarios.doc/gop_03/topics/bj60043_.htm) and it was fine, fast and i dont have any problem, so I still dont agree with your point, at least until you provide some IBM documentation

Comment: Hello, I think your link is definitely validating my response : SET OutputRoot.XMLNSC = InputRoot.DFDL. This means the message was parsed in DFDL, as I explained in my answer. I am not against processing DFDL in ESQL, but processing a csv directly would mean parsing it (doing split on the ',' and '<CR><LF>'). Regarding the message size, I searched a bit and I cannot find this link anymore, maybe it is not relevant anymore with IIB10 (at the time I was working with WMB8.0.0.4)